# Delphi 6: How to search a dynamic array for sub-string quickly?

Tags: delphi, search, arrays, char

How can I search a dynamic array of char in Delphi 6 for a sub-string and get back an index to a match, not a pointer?  I've seen functions in Delphi 6 that do this for strings but not for dynamic char arrays.  There is a function called SearchBuf but that function returns a PChar pointer to the match location when what I need is the array index of the match.

Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a dynamic array of characters? I can't think of a single advantage they offer over strings.

Comment: I am moving data in out between functions that manage audio data in char array format.  It's a legacy code thing.

Comment: If you set the length of a string variable to the size of your dynamic array, then you can type-cast that string to PChar and you'll have an equally good character array for the function to read or fill.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer to the match, simply subtract the pointer to the first character, and you'll have your index.

```
var
  Buf, Result: PChar;
  Index: Integer;

Result := SearchBuf(Buf, ...);
if Assigned(Result) then
  Index := Result - Buf
else
  Index := -1; // not found
```

I'm pretty sure that pointer arithmetic is allowed in Delphi 6. If not, then type-cast the pointers to integral types first:

```
Index := Cardinal(Result) - Cardinal(Buf);
```